# Wi-fi not connecting to Android Studio emulators

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, android-emulator

My windows m/c's Wi-fi not connecting to Android Studio emulators. I have been using Emulators last one year or so, I have never faced this type of issue. Whenever I was starting Emulators, Wi-fi was getting connected immediately automatically. But last few day it wasn't happening. Wi-fi not getting connected in Emulators. I have tried so many things but it couldn't get solved.

Interestingly Wi-fi connecting in *Genymotion* android emulators.

Android studio setting

```
Settings/Appearence & Behaviour/System settings/HTTP Proxy
```

No Proxy Enabled.

Emulator setting

[image]

Comment: Did you tried creating a new one ?

Comment: I created nearly 5 Emulators. Still same issue even I informed networking team they said no idea.

Comment: Tried wipe data ?

Comment: @Vivek Mishra- I tried this, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After super struggle I found answer. For windows o/s go to

```
Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections
```

- Select your internet connected adapter
- Right click--Properties
- Check & Select IPv4(if already checked IPv4 than select so property will be activated)
- Click properties
- Check 2nd radio  button-- Use the following DSN server addresses
- Enter DNS address as 8.8.8.8 click Ok.

To not to confuse, IPv4 =Internet Protocol Version 4(TCP/IPv4) option

That's finish..Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the version of Android Studio to the latest one and when creating a new emulator make sure that the emulator has GooglePlay service enabled, 
as also shown down below:

[image]

I hope this will save your troubles.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Where to Enable GooglePlay service? do you mean second option Play Store should show play store symbol?  as it is showing in your screenshot.

Comment: Exactly, the play store symbol should be visible on the targeted device which you like to instantiate. Please let me know if it works